# Remote Event Receiver(existing) stops working when a new remote event receiver is added

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver

I'm not sure what's going wrong, hoping someone to correct me here. I have an itemadding RER which works well and smooth, the problem occurs when i add one more to the tenant. The Second RER actually starts working after the deploy and the first RER(existing) actually stops responding. May i know why is this happening? Btw, i'm using different client ID and client secret for both the app.

Comment: Please provide some code or give us more information on what method of adding ReRs you have used.

Comment: @piotrSulowski, First RER is on 'item adding' and the second RER is on 'item added'event. It doesn't matter what type of event i use, it always breaks the existing app when i deploy the new one. In the AppEventReceiver.svc.cs file i handle appinstalled and appuninstalling event, and in another file my itemadding logic fires.

i could succesfully deploy the app, but the problem is the existing app stops working and the new one begins to work. i'm using trail azure account, is there an limitation that a same publishing profile cannot be used ?